# Create a QR generator API for Ruby (2.2.2) on Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a main Ruby on Rails app, which generates links and associated PDF files. What I want is to generate a QR code for each one of the links, so I can paste them in the PDF files.

I know the rqrcode gem, but my problem is that the app is in Ruby 2.2.2, and the gem works from version 2.3 on. I can´t update the Ruby version for irrelevant reasons, so that´s not an option. So I want to create an API to which I pass the link, and it returns me the QR code via JSON. This API will be in Ruby 3.1.2 so I can use the rqrcode gem. The thing is that in every RoR API tutorials, they configure the storage and many other things that I think are not necessary in my case. I want to make this API as minimal as possible, and I don't know where to start.

Comment: You might want to read about [using Rails for API-only Applications](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html) in the official Rails Guides.

Comment: Btw there are a [couple of security vulnerabilities in Ruby 2.2.2](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-7252/product_id-12215/version_id-543881/Ruby-lang-Ruby-2.2.2.html). I would argue they are not _irrelevant_ and should be a good reason to update your application.

Comment: Yhea, I read the documentation.. But I'm a little lost. I know how to use Ruby on Rails, but I never really built an API with it. I need some guidance... And the 'irrelevant reasons' are irrelevant because in doesn't depend on me. I mean, if it was by me I would have updated a long time ago.